# Código roda no Jupyter e no VSC da erro

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Rodo este código pelo Jupyter e ele roda normalmente, mas quando tento rodar este mesmo código no Visual Studio Code ele da o seguinte erro: "File b'Salaries.csv' does not exist" diz que o arquivo não existe, mas existe sim.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv', sep=',', decimal='.')
print(df)
```

Comment: Existe, mas está na mesma pasta que o script Python?

Comment: sim, por isso não estou entendendo, pois no Jupyter o script roda normalmente e no Visual Studio não há identificação do arquivo.

Comment: Eles estão exatamente no mesmo diretório.

Comment: Consegue fazer um [mcve] no Repl.it reproduzindo o problema?

Comment: editei e pus uma foto com todo o problema em si na IDE

Comment: Couzer, tentou passar o diretório completo para fazer um teste?

Comment: sim e diz a mesma coisa

Comment: ahh esqueci de mencionar que ele identifica o read_html, mas o read_csv não

Comment: O problema era no próprio arquivo, não me perguntem o que, pois não sei, mas tentei uma nova lista com o mesmo formato de arquivo e deu certo, grato por tentarem ajudar.